# Setting width of a TD with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to set the width of a TD based on the window width minus an amount of pixels and make it responsive. I am specifically trying to use this to make a page the size of the window for a live stream and chat, but It does not seem to work with width minus an amount of pixels I set.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="table_big"> 
    <tr>
        <td id="player_table">Content is not important just text</td>
        <td id="chat_table">Content is not important just text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
    function resize()
    {
        var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
        if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
            //Non-IE
            myWidth = window.innerWidth;
            myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||                             document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 4 compatible
            myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
        document.getElementById("chat").height = myHeight* 0.78 + 'px';
        document.getElementById("width").width = myWidth ;
        document.getElementById("table_big").height = myHeight + 'px';
        document.getElementById("chat_table").width = '340px';
        document.getElementById("player_table").width = myWidth - '340px';
    }
    resize();
</script>
```

Fixed by Shashank. The line `document.getElementById("width").width = myWidth;` was returning null and I removed the px from all of them too

Comment: Why not set it to 100% width and have responsive CSS?

Comment: Glad to see you're supporting IE4, it still has a market share of over 0.0001%.

Comment: So many issues, I don't even know where to begin. But here is one prominent issue, the expression: `myWidth - '340px'` is gonna be NaN. Also "px" is for CSS, not HTML attributes.

Comment: @Shashank Well then do you know how to fix it I have tried just about everything I could think of. It is supposed to re-size the table whenever the window is re-sized, but the left TD needs to be just 340 pixels wide. The other side needs to be as wide as possible minus the 340 pixels.

Comment: set it to `myWidth - 340`. In Javascript, subtracting a string gives you NaN (not a number). Take out all the 'px' things, you only use those for styling. ALso if `document.getElementById("chat")` returns null or undefined, your javascript will get an error when you try to access the width or height property of null/undefined. So make sure those elements actually exist in your DOM or the script will halt early on.

Comment: Additionally, you should be using firebug on mozilla firefox or some other javascript debugger so you can see the console and all the error messages. With that, you can use `console.log()` function to give yourself info about the state of your code. this is useful for checking the value of expressions and variables and such.

Comment: @Shashank Thanks the ID of "width" was returning null and removing that fixed it, thanks so much.